# Case-sensitive keyboard shortcuts

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, case-sensitive

I'd like some map/remap/nmap/etc. commands to be case sensitive, e.g. "<C-I>" vs. "<C-i>".

I checked Google and :help map, but was unable to find this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you currently can't combine control with case-sensitivity in vim or gvim (I'm using 7.2).  I might expect this to be a limitation of terminals for the former, but not the latter.

I tested it by typing this in a buffer:

> map <c-i> :echo "c-i"<cr>
>   map <c-s-i> :echo "c-s-i"<cr>

Yank those lines, then :@" (when executes register " as commands).  Verifying the maps with :map <c-i> and <c-s-i> shows the problem: <c-i> is <tab>, and only the last one takes effect, with the shift being ignored.

For alt, <a-i> and <a-s-i> do work as expected in gvim

In terminal vim, those two get mapped to é and É (at least here, check with ":map <a-i>" as above), and typing é/É directly (I use dead keys) does invoke the mapping.  Actually doing a-i or a-s-i just enters insert mode.

Of course, non-control and non-alt maps work case-sensitively.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Add `S` for Shift</strike>

```
<C-S-i>
```

If you use your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, (1) what on earth for?, and (2) you'll have problems. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_CapsLock_work_in_Vim) if this is your situation.

My bad.

Cannot be done, by design, with printable characters. The approach above *does* work with <kbd>F1</kbd> *et al*, such as `<C-S-F8>`. See [this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Maping-Ctrl-Shift-s-problems-td1182827.html) for more.

My workaround would be to map it to something entirely different and obscure, and use AutoHotkey or similar to substitute the combination only for the uppercase variant.

Comment: This does not work for me in vim or gvim, 7.2.330. Specifically, "map <c-i>" is ignored and "map <c-s-i>" is used when I press 'i' while holding control but not shift. I defined the c-s-i mapping last, and that appears to matter.

Comment: doesn't work; try :map <C-o> k    :map <C-S-o> j. Both end up being the latter command (regardless of which order they are input). EDIT -- ditto what Roger said.

Answer (score 5):

Docs say that "CTRL-A and CTRL-a are equivalent".

Relevant part from `:help notation`

```
CTRL-{char}   {char} typed as a control character; that is, typing {char}
              while holding the CTRL key down.  The case of {char} does not
              matter; thus CTRL-A and CTRL-a are equivalent.  But on some
              terminals, using the SHIFT key will produce another code,
              don't use it then.
```

(not intended as an answer, but as relevant info for anybody comming from search engine regarding case sensitivity)